# Список всех участников чата aiogram 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Как получить абсолютно всех участников чата в aiogram 3 зная только айди чата. Смотрел другие форумы, но ответ находил только либо для старой версии, либо не работающие функции.

Есть идея, как можно получать список всех пользователей чата: при каждом сообщении записывать id пользователя в множество и потом по каждому id получать пользователя, но если пользователь долгое время не писал, или писал, пока бот был выключен, тогда не сработает.

**Кто может помочь, кто знает как получить список пользователей в последней версии aiogram?**

Comment: Именно через aiogram, нельзя этот сделать, телеграмм не дает такой возможности, можно сделать проверку, есть ли такой пользователь в чате или в бд записывать каждого пользователя или например в связку взять pyrogram

Comment: @Baggrisha, я знаю и понимаю это, вот поэтому и пишу вопрос на форум, чтобы кто-то предоставил рабочий вариант кода.

Comment: В aiogram НЕЛЬЗЯ получить список всех пользователей, можешь воспользоваться pyrogram , https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_members

Comment: @Baggrisha я понял, что НЕЛЬЗЯ, и прошу вас, или кого-нибудь другого, предоставить РАБОЧИЙ вариант кода, неважно какой, главное чтобы свою функцию выполнял.

Comment: я ж скинул ссылку выше.        from pyrogram import enums

# Get members
async for member in app.get_chat_members(chat_id):
    print(member)

# Get administrators
administrators = []
async for m in app.get_chat_members(chat_id, filter=enums.ChatMembersFilter.ADMINISTRATORS):
    administrators.append(m)

# Get bots
bots = []
async for m in app.get_chat_members(chat_id, filter=enums.ChatMembersFilter.BOTS):
    bots.append(m)

Comment: Ну а как этим пользоваться? Откуда берётся переменная app и асинхронные функции?

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/quickstart , туда тупо добавляешь то, что я тебе скинул выше